# How to get the count of an array of objects defined in an interface?

Tags: iphone, ios

I have an interface definition like this:

```
@interface MasterPanelsController : UIViewController {
    PanelSuperclass *panels[3];
}
```

I'm trying to programmatically get the count of my `panels` array, but `[panels count]` and `sizeof(panels)` don't work. How can I determine the size of this array?

(Note: `PanelSuperclass` is a subclass of `UIView`)

Comment: Why would you keep ObjC objects in a C array?

Comment: How about [panels length] ? (if you have to store the, this way I mean)

Comment: Why not use NSArray instead of C arrays?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using:

```
int arrayCount = sizeof(panels) / sizeof(panels[0]);
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a C array of PanelSuperclass pointers, to get number of items, this C array can hold call the following:

```
sizeof(panels)/sizeof(panels[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use c style arrays for objective-c objects. Use NSArray instead.

Comment: It didn't answer my question. If you edit and include an explanation of what the potential repercussions of this approach are, I'll undo.

Comment: well ok that's true, but i won't change it and tell you how to do something that you shouldn't do. You'll end up with really really bad code!